# Can't open chrome in incognito with Python

Tags: python, google-chrome

I want to open a chrome window in incognito mode with python.

I've seen others examples but always open a new tab in normal mode

```
import webbrowser

    browser_path = 'C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe --incognito %s'
    webbrowser.get(browser_path)
    webbrowser.open_new('www.google.com')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a controller object for your browser type (in this case, chrome in incognito mode) using "get" method. Once you have the object, you can call "open_new" method.
This is how I did it:

```
import webbrowser

browser_path = '"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --incognito %s'
browser = webbrowser.get(browser_path) 
browser.open_new('www.google.com')
```